# Посчитать суммарную зарплату сотрудников в подразделении использую stream API

Tags: java

Мне необходимо подсчитать суммарную зарплату сотрудников в подразделении использую stream API. Я загружаю информацию о сотрудниках в репозиторий, информация о каждом сотриднике представлена в классе Person.
Мне нужно сформировать  Map где будет содержаться подразделение и суммарная з/п всех сотрудников данного подразделения.
Вот мой код:

```
List<String> listNames=new ArrayList<String>();

            Set<String> setNames=new HashSet<String>();

            setNames=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());



             List<BigDecimal> listSalary=new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

            Map<String, Integer> nameSalary=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
          //  nameSalary=r.toList().stream().flatMap(x->Stream.of(x.getDivision().getName(),x.getSalary())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

           ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));
             ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));

            listNames=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()+x.hashCode()).collect(Collectors.toList());
             listSalary=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getSalary()).collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<Integer> intSalary = listSalary.stream().map(BigDecimal::intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
           /*Map<String, BigDecimal> countDivisionSalary = IntStream.range(0, setNames.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(setNames, listSalary::get));*/

          Map<String, Integer> countDivisionSalary = IntStream.range(0, listNames.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(listNames::get, longsSalary::get));




       Map<String, Integer> summaryMap = r.toList().stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(listNames::get,
                Collectors.summingInt(longsSalary::get)));



            for (Map.Entry entry : summaryMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Podrazdelenie: " + entry.getKey()+"Sum Salary"+entry.getValue());
        }

}
```

Основная проблема заключается в том что:
1) з/п по заданию у меня типа BigDecimal, поэтому 
 методы Collectors.summingInt()/Collectors.summingLong()/Collectors.Double() применить нельзя
2) название подразделение представлено в классе Division, а в классе Person(который хранит информация о сотрудниках) поэтому можно получить Collectors.groupingBy(IPerson::getDivision) вместо Collectors.groupingBy(IPerson::getDivision.getName())
Чтобы решить приведённые выше проблемы я записал подразделения в список  listNames=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()+x.hashCode()).collect(Collectors.toList());
А зарплату сотрудников в список

```
 listSalary=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getSalary()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

После чего привел данный список к типу int:

```
List<Integer> intSalary = listSalary.stream().map(BigDecimal::intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

И попытался записать значения списков listSalary и intSalary в Map с группировкой и суммированием:

```
Map<String, Integer> summaryMap = r.toList().stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(listNames::get,
                Collectors.summingInt(longsSalary::get)));
```

но среда выдаёт ошибку no suitable method found  for collect
Помогите пожалуйста разобраться с проблемой.

Код класса LoadRepository:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.function.Function;
import static java.util.function.Function.identity;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import javafx.util.Pair;

/**
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class LoadRepository {

    private Repository r;
    private int size=2000;

    public Repository getR() {
        return r;
    }

    public void setR(Repository r) {
        this.r = r;
    }

    public LoadRepository() {
        r=new Repository(size);
    }



    public void readFromFileInRepository(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception {
       // Repository r = new Repository(2000);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        File f = new File(fileName);
        BufferedReader fin = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f));

        String line;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(fileName));

        while (in.hasNextLine()) {

            String buf = in.nextLine();
            if (buf.startsWith("id")) {
                ;
            } else {
                String[] bufArray = buf.split(";");

                int id = Integer.parseInt(bufArray[0]);
                String firstName = bufArray[1];
                String lastName = bufArray[2];
                Gender gender = Gender.valueOf(bufArray[3].toUpperCase());
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.yyyy");

                LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(bufArray[4], formatter);

                String Name = bufArray[5];

                IDivision div = new Division(Name);

                BigDecimal money = new BigDecimal(bufArray[6]);

                IPerson bufObject = new Person(id, firstName, lastName, gender, date, div, money);

                if (bufObject != null) {
                    r.add(bufObject);
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public Stream<IPerson> threeMethod()
    {
       return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("aa"));
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;

    }

      public Stream<IPerson> twoMethod()
    {
        BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(5000);
       return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("a")).filter(s->s.getAge()>30).filter(s->s.getSalary().compareTo(valDouble)<0);
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;

    }

        public   Map<Integer, Long> fourMethod()
    {
       // BigDecimal valDouble = new BigDecimal(5000);
      // return r.toList().stream().filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("a")).filter(s->s.getAge()>30).filter(s->s.getSalary().compareTo(valDouble)<0);
       //stream.filter(s -> s.getFirstName().contains("AA"));
       //return stream;
     //  Map<Integer,Integer> hm= new HashMap<>();
     //  HashMap<int,int>= r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson,0));
    // hm.put(r.toList().stream().filter(s->s.getBirthdate().getYear()>0), size);
 Set<Integer> set1=new HashSet<Integer>();
 Set<Integer> set2=new HashSet<Integer>();

 List<Integer> list1=new ArrayList<Integer>();

 set1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
 list1=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).collect(Collectors.toList());

       r.toList().stream().filter(s->s.getBirthdate().getYear()==s.getBirthdate().getYear()).count();

    //    r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear());

//   Set<Integer> duplicated = r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).filter(i -> Collections.frequency(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), i) >1)
               // .collect(Collectors.toSet());
  /* System.out.println("Years:");
   for(int i:set1) System.out.println(i);
   System.out.println("Count of years:");
    for(int i:duplicated) System.out.println(i);*/
  /*Map<Integer, Integer> yearDuplicates = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
  yearDuplicates.put(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()).count());
  System.out.println("Years duplicates:");
    for (Map.Entry entry : yearDuplicates.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Year: " + entry.getKey() + " Count: "
        + entry.getValue());
}*/
 // Map<Integer, Integer> letterToCount =
          // list1.stream().collect(groupingBy(identity(), counting()));
         // return r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), v -> 1L, Long::sum));
/*    Set<Integer> set3=   set2.stream()
       .filter(t -> Collections.frequency(r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getBirthdate().getYear()), t) > 1).collect(Collectors.toSet());*/
     /*   System.out.println("Count years");
       for(int i:set3) System.out.println(i);*/



       Map<Integer, Long> countForYear = list1.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));




       /*for (Map.Entry entry : countForYear.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Year: " + entry.getKey() + " Count: "
        + entry.getValue());

    }*/
        return countForYear;




}
        public void oneMethod()
        {
            List<String> listNames=new ArrayList<String>();

            Set<String> setNames=new HashSet<String>();

            setNames=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()).collect(Collectors.toSet());



             List<BigDecimal> listSalary=new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();

            Map<String, Integer> nameSalary=new HashMap<String, Integer>();
          //  nameSalary=r.toList().stream().flatMap(x->Stream.of(x.getDivision().getName(),x.getSalary())).collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

           ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));
             ///nameSalary=r.toList().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(IPerson::getDivision,IPerson::getSalary));

            listNames=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getDivision().getName()+x.hashCode()).collect(Collectors.toList());
             listSalary=r.toList().stream().map(x->x.getSalary()).collect(Collectors.toList());
 List<Integer> longsSalary = listSalary.stream().map(BigDecimal::intValue).collect(Collectors.toList());
           /*Map<String, BigDecimal> countDivisionSalary = IntStream.range(0, setNames.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(setNames, listSalary::get));*/

          Map<String, Integer> countDivisionSalary = IntStream.range(0, listNames.size()).boxed()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(listNames::get, longsSalary::get));




       Map<String, Integer> summaryMap = r.toList().stream().
                collect(Collectors.groupingBy(listNames::get,
                Collectors.summingInt(longsSalary::get)));



            for (Map.Entry entry : summaryMap.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Podrazdelenie: " + entry.getKey()+"Sum Salary"+entry.getValue());
        }

}
}
```

Код класса Person:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

import java.math.BigDecimal;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

import org.joda.time.Period;

/**
 * Class Person contains four field: 1) id as identifikator; 2) Name-Name Father
 * Surname; 3) date - date birthday 4) sex - sex Person
 *
 * Methods getDate(),getSex(),getId(), getName() -returns values fields class
 * Methods setDate(),setSex(),setId(), setName() -set values fields class
 *
 * Method difference_date() -calcute age Person
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class Person implements IPerson {

    /**
     * Filed "id" as identifikator.
     *
     */
    private int id;

    /**
     * Filed "Name"-Name Father Surname.
     *
     */


    private String FirstName;

    private String LastName;

    private LocalDate Birthdate;

    /**
     * Filed date - date birthday.
     *
     */


    /**
     * Filed Gender - sex Person.
     *
     */


    private Gender Gender;

    /**
     * Filed Salary - Salary for Person.
     *
     */

    private BigDecimal Salary;

    public IDivision IDivision;





    /**
     * Method getId() return Id.
     *
     * @return
     */
    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }



    /**
     * Method setId set field Id.
     *
     * @param id
     */
    public final void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }




 /**
     * Method getFirstName return filedt FirstName.
     *

     */

    public String getFirstName() {
        return FirstName;
    }

    /**
     * Method getFirstName set filed FirstName.
     *
     * @param FirstName
     */

    public String setFirstName(String FirstName) {
        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        return this.FirstName;

    }

    /**
     * Method getlastName return filed LastName.
     *

     */
    public String getLastName() {
        return LastName;
    }

    /**
     * Method setLastName set filed LastName.
     *
     * @param FirstName
     */
    public String setLastName(String LastName) {
        this.LastName = LastName;
        return this.LastName;
    }
/**
     * Method getBirthdate return filed Birthdate.
     *

     */
    public LocalDate getBirthdate() {
        return Birthdate;
    }

     /**
     * Method setBirthdate set filed Birthdate.
     *
     * @param Birthdate

     */
    public LocalDate setBirthdate(LocalDate Birthdate) {
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
        return this.Birthdate;
    }

    /**
     * Method getSalary return filed Salary.
     *

     */
    public BigDecimal getSalary() {
        return Salary;
    }

    /**
     * Method setSalary set filed Salary.
     *
     * @param Salary
     */
    public void setSalary(BigDecimal Salary) {
        this.Salary = Salary;
    }

     /**
     * Method getGender return  gender Person.
     *

     */
    public Gender getGender() {
        return Gender;
    }

     /**
     * Method setGender set gender Person.
     *
     * @param Gender
     */
    public void setGender(Gender Gender) {
        this.Gender = Gender;
    }

    /**
     * Method getDivision return gender Person.
     *
     */
    public IDivision getDivision() {
        return IDivision;
    }


    /**
     * Method getDivision return field setDivision.
     *
     * @param division
     */
    public void setDivision(IDivision division) {
        this.IDivision = IDivision;
    }

    /**
     * This is constructor.
     *
     * @param id
     * @param FirstName
     * @param Name
     * @param Birthdate
     * @param Gender
     * @param Salary
     *
     */
    public Person(int id, String FirstName, String LastName, Gender Gender,LocalDate Birthdate,  String Name, BigDecimal Salary) {

        this.id = id;

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
         this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;


        this.IDivision.setName(Name);
        this.Salary = Salary;

    }

    public Person(int id, String FirstName, String LastName,Gender Gender, LocalDate Birthdate, IDivision IDivision, BigDecimal Salary ) {
        this.id = id;

        this.FirstName = FirstName;
        this.LastName = LastName;
        this.Gender = Gender;
        this.Birthdate = Birthdate;
        this.IDivision = IDivision;
        this.Salary = Salary;

    }



    /**
     * Method getAge calculate and print age Person.
     */
    public Integer getAge() {
        LocalDate now = LocalDate.now();

       //Period p = new Period(date, now);

        int years = (int) ChronoUnit.YEARS.between(Birthdate, now);

        return years;
    }

}
```

Код класса Division:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package com.mycompany.laba1;

/**
 *
 * @author Data
 */
public class Division implements IDivision {

    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Division( String name) {

        this.name = name;
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может я не до конца понял описанную проблему... Исходя из изложенного, имея List типизированный IPerson необходимо получить Map, типизированный названием подразделения и суммарной зарплатой работников каждого подразделения, при этом все нужно сделать в стриме.
Тогда это выглядит примерно так:

```
Map<String, BigDecimal> result = IPersonList.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->p.getDivision().getName(),
                Collectors.mapping(IPerson::getSalary, Collectors.reducing(BigDecimal.ZERO, BigDecimal::add))));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Всё заработало!

Comment: Не за что))))))